# Uploading large file word document using microsoft graph API using uploadsession

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files

I am uploading word document using microsoft graph UploadSession. Document uploaded successfully and received uploaded file link which is open in next browser tab using application. But all the data are displays in single line. There is no line breaks or paragraph. How to add content-type to upload and display data as it is in local file or any other way to upload document. I am following these instructions:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/large-file-upload?tabs=java

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you repro the issue outside of your application (say, Graph Explorer or POSTMAN)?

Comment: If its drive item then you can set the content-type and here's the [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)